# CURSOR PL/SQL ORACLE

Tags: oracle, join, plsql, cursor

i've tried to run this cursor but i got an error that says

> ERROR at line 7: ORA-06550: line 7, column 31: PLS-00357:
>
> Table,View Or Sequence reference 'CATEGORY.CATEGORY_NAME' not allowed
>   in this context
>
> ORA-06550: line 7, column 1:
>
> PL/SQL: Statement ignored

here's the pl/sql syntax that i used :

```
DECLARE
CURSOR check_stock IS
select category.category_name, item.item_name, item_stock from category join item on category.id_category = item.id_category;
BEGIN
FOR stock IN check
LOOP
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(category.category_name ||' '||item.item_name ||' '|| item.stock);
END LOOP;
END;
```

can somebody fix this issue ? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't reference table names, but cursor variable:

```
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(stock.category_name ||' '||stock.item_name ||' '|| stock.stock);
                     -----                      -----                   -----
```